# How to trigger multiple "child" Jobs from a "mother" Job using Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a `Job` that looks into a configuration table and I would like it to trigger a `Job` per configuration entry using the values from the table.

The first `Job` comprises of a single `Tasklet` that does the config table lookup then triggers a subsequent `Job` per entry.

Mother `Job` code:

```
@Configuration
public class RunProcessesJobConfig {

    ... // steps, jobs factory init
    @Autowired
    private Tasklet runProcessTask;    

    @Bean
    public Step runProcessStep() {
        return steps.get("runProcessStep")
                .tasklet(runProcessTask)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job runProcessJob() {
        return jobs.get("runProcessJob")
                .start(runProcessStep())
                .build();
    }
}
```

The way I'm currently trying to implement it is by Autowiring a `JobLauncher` and the `Job` I need into the `Tasklet` and running the `Job` from there.

'RunProcessTask' - gets autowired into job config above:

```
@Autowired
Job myJob;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution sc, ChunkContext cc) throws Exception {

    List<DeployCfg> deployCfgs = da.getJobCfgs();

    for (DeployCfg deployCfg : deployCfgs) {
        String cfg1 = deployCfg.getCfg1();
        String cfg2 = deployCfg.getCfg2();
        String cfg3 = deployCfg.getCfg3();

        // trigger job per config
        new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("cfg1", cfg1)
                .addString("cfg2", cfg2)
                .addString("cfg3", cfg3);

        final JobExecution jobExec = jobLauncher.run(myJob, new JobParameters());
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

When I try executing the Mother `Job` I get an `TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException: Transaction manager [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] does not support transaction suspension` error along the `jobLauncher.run(...)` line.

I'm thinking running a Job within another Job messes up with Spring Batch's Transaction Manager. Any ideas on how to do this?

Additional version info:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.9.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-batch
```

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Cloud Data Flow?  We have something that does this already called a composed task (via the Composed Task Runner).

Comment: @MichaelMinella is such a use-case supported in Spring Batch?

Comment: You can create your own batch job that does this.  That's what we did with the composed task runner.